# How to handle a return type Maybe<unknown>

Tags: typescript, ethereum, metamask

Iam using typescript and iam trying to get the accounts from the current user like its showed on the metamask official documentation [Metamask Doc](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations):

```
const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
                  method: "eth_accounts",
                });
```

The call to the `request` function returns a result with the `Maybe<unknown>` type.

Then iam trying to access the first element of accounts like this because its supposed to be an array of string :

```
accounts[0]
```

But i have the following errors:

```
Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ts(2533)

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Partial<unknown>'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Partial<unknown>'.ts(7053)
```

So, how can i manage to handle this situation?
I need to properly get the return of the `request` function and make typescript accept it as an array of string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors indicate that the returned value from the request might be null, undefined or even not-an-array value. So you have to check those cases before accessing its value.

```js
const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
  method: "eth_accounts",
}); 
if (accounts && Array.isArray(accounts)) {
  // Here you can access accounts[0]
} else {
  // Handle errors here if accounts is not valid. 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Iam learning typescript and this solution worked for me and teached me how to manage this kind of situations.